# Visual Studio 2008 - How can I create a Multi-Touch Test Form - Requiring two buttons to be pressed simultaneously to continue

Tags: forms, visual-studio-2008, multi-touch

Does anyone know any way to create a simple form in Visual Studio 2008 that contains two buttons, Button 1 and Button 2 and for them to require that both are pressed simultaneously in order to perform an action?

I need to test a bunch of multi-touch screens so I thought I'd make a multi-touch app if I can.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input for each button and when you click on one of those buttons you set the value of the input. And then you can use a validator which checks whether the values of the inputs meets the desired values.